# Rewiring a UK dimmer switch with a Wifi switch

Tags: switch, wifi

I've just bought a wifi switch and was wondering if somebody could tell me which wire goes to which please? I'm thinking the following?

L = Live (Brown)
L1 = Arrow over tilde??
N = Blue (Neutral)
Earth = Wrapped up

Thank you

Current Varilight dimmer switch:
[image: current switch]

To new wifi switch:
[image: new switch]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the switch box?

Comment: What is make and model of new wifi switch?

Comment: Thanks both. Re. make model, it's a random brand from Amazon [link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07FMJHQFF/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). Re. back of the box, is there anything specific you're looking for so I can take a better shot? Similar one below.

![link](https://i.imgur.com/Z1xWOu8.jpg)

Comment: Related. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/151051/installing-a-smart-light-switch

Answer (score 1):

Put the two blues into the N connector

The browns go into L and L1, but you have to get them the right way round.

one of the browns goes to the lamp and the other comes from the supply (you will probably need to check for voltage to determine which is from the supply)

The supply brown goes into L and the lamp brouwn into L1

join the earth wires with an approved joiner. over here earths need two screw joiner while other conductors don't, so you probably shouldn't use that joiner that came off the blue wires.

Answer (score 1):

Brown from main to L, brown from light to L1 blue to N: take a 4cm piece of blu wire and pigtail it to other blues, PE connect together the two PE with another wire nut because your new dimmer is class II and don't need the **P**rotective **E**arth.

If you don't have a wire-nut just put the two blues together into the N place and recycle the nut you have for the PEs.