# Is adding a Time Delay/Dual Element Fuse a good idea for pump motor install

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electric-motor

I have 240v circuit with 12awg wire that will service a 3/4hp motor (about 5amps max at 240v).  That circuit is protected by a standard 20amp breaker.

I was wondering if it is a good idea/warranted to put in a 10amp time-delay fuse at the motor as extra protection?

Like this for example.  [600V Slow Blow Class CC Time Delay Fuse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LX11Z3E)

Problem with this style fuse I can't find a single fuse holder/block and the three place ones are 6 times the price of a fuse on ebay.

Can one use a more standard glass/ceramic type fuse for this application?  like this [Bussmann MDA 10A 250v Slow Blow Time Delay Ceramic Fuse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007ZTI7NG) because holders for this are common and cheap.

Comment: Does the motor have thermal overload protection built in?  Can you post a photo of the nameplate?

Comment: Don't have the pump yet.  But manual says "For safety, the pump motor has resetting thermal protector that automatically will turn off the pump
if it becomes too hot." so I guess that is a yes.

Comment: Most motors have a resetting thermostat.  Pumps are water cooled.  If they run in a dry well, they burn out if not thermally protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real need to put a 10A fuse on it in addition to the breaker. The 20A breaker will be enough protection regarding overload and short circuits.

The only recommendation I would give is to put it on a GFCI because it's for a pump in a presumably wet location.

Answer (score 0):

Regular breakers are *already* time-delay/dual-element, so you don't need an extra device for this.  You could just  **downbreaker** at the panel.  Change the 20A breaker for a 15, or if you're willing to hunt down a 10A, do that.

Each series point in a circuit has exactly the same current, so it doesn't matter where the breaker/fuse is located.

Besides, fuseholders may be readily available as components, but that doesn't mean it's easy to mount them in a safe, Code-legal and serviceable manner.

Speaking of components.... You must stop buying electrical components on eBay, AliExpress/AliBaba, or Amazon **Marketplace**. (For the difference [see this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/132745/47125)).  This stuff is almost all cheap Cheese junk that has never, and will never, see the inside of a reputable testing lab like Underwriter's Laboratories (UL).

For mains wiring this type of imported junk is prohibited by NEC 110.2, which requires items be **approved** (by your local authority, but they defer to UL and comparable labs such as CSA or TUV).  CE is not a testing lab.

Sellers on Amazon Marketplace lie constantly about "By (manufacturer)", but in all fairness, [this one looks legit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007ZTI7NG). Here, *it appears* the US factory is using  [Amazon's warehouse as a drop-shipper](https://services.amazon.com/fulfillment-by-amazon/benefits.html) so they don't need to staff their own shipping department.  When you do this -- a few more clicks and you're on Amazon Marketplace, and Prime members get free 2-day shipping.

Comment: Actually, the first link looks like manufacturer ship via Amazon warehouse. The second one appears to be generic stuff of possibly dubious quality.

Comment: @manassehkatz Good catch, I clarified..

Comment: Actually, it looked to me like the other way around. Unless I'm really confused...

Comment: @manassehkatz oh I see what you mean.  "Sold from and ships by X" is safer **if** they ship from the United States [or other country with good safety and import standards].  However many are ePacket delivery from China, usually Shenzhen where the US Postal Service has a facility with very low shipping rates.

Comment: Bottom line is **caveat emptor**.

Answer (score 0):

In passing:  If you haven't bought the pump yet, give thought to the 3 phase variable frequency drive pumps.  They are more expensive, but they use frequency control to keep the pressure nearly constant if you are drawing more than 1 gpm.  This reduces pump cycling, and keeps the water level in the well more constant.  Net result:  fewer future problems.  Here, the main supplier of these is Gould.

Answer (score 0):

### Thermal protection matters

Since your pump motor, according to its documentation (assuming it is accurate) has integral thermal overload protection, then you don't need to provide anything besides the branch-circuit short-circuit (and possibly ground-fault) protection at the panel.  This means that your existing 20A breaker is fine provided the wiring is sized appropriately: there is no need for a fuse or a downsized breaker to protect the motor from overload.